# Replace a string containing parentheses with a float in pandas

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, replace

I have a dataset with a column of strings which I want to convert to floats.  However the column has a single entry containing a number within parentheses (which means to be a negative number).  I tried different ways --indirect and direct-- to replace the value with a representation that would enable me to convert it to float but I have been failing and I don't understand why:

Here is the row with the digit under parentheses as a string:

[image]

My code:

```
mask1 = purchases.Amount.str.contains('\(').fillna(False)

purchases.loc[mask1, :]['Amount'] = purchases.loc[mask1, :]['Amount'].str.replace('\(', '-').str.replace('\)', '')

purchases.loc[mask2, :]['Amount'] = purchases.loc[mask2, :]['Amount'].str.replace('\s+', '').str.replace('[a-z]+', '') 

# Both fail to replace

purchases.loc[mask1, :]['Amount'] = '-29.99'  # direct assignment also fails
```

The result:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?  How can I correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `rstrip` for remove last `)`, then replace `(` and last convert to floats:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Amount': ['(29.29)', '(39.39)', '12.5', '340']})
df['Amount'] = df['Amount'].str.strip(')').str.replace('\(', '-').astype(float)
print (df)
   Amount
0  -29.29
1  -39.39
2   12.50
3  340.00
```

Your solutions are very close, what you need, only use `loc` with columns namef for avoid [chain indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/user_guide/indexing.html#evaluation-order-matters):

```
mask1 = purchases.Amount.str.contains('\(').fillna(False)

purchases.loc[mask1, 'Amount'] = purchases.loc[mask1, 'Amount'].str.replace('\(', '-').str.replace('\)', '')

purchases.loc[mask2, 'Amount'] = purchases.loc[mask2, 'Amount'].str.replace('\s+', '').str.replace('[a-z]+', '')
```

---

```
purchases.loc[mask1, 'Amount'] = '-29.99'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Amount': ['(29.29)', '29.29']})
print(df)

df['Amount']=df.Amount.apply(lambda x: -float(x[1:-1]) if x[0] == '(' else float(x))
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

Result:

```
    Amount
0  (29.29)
1    29.29

   Amount
0  -29.29
1   29.29

Amount    float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check if the string is surrounded by brackets, and if it is, strip them.

```
from decimal import Decimal

def get_amount(s):
    if s[0] == '(' and s[-1] == ')':
        return Decimal(s[1:-1])
    else:
        return Decimal(s)
```